# Cannot locate Class element Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Im trying to create an automated instagram bot and encountered a problem when trying to select and click a button (the button in question is a 'stories' button):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/chong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        self.base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com'
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
        element.send_keys("mysuername")

        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
        element.send_keys("mypassword")

        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("cmbtv")
        element.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.get('{}/{}'.format(self.base_url, 'fatcatharvey'))
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('tUtVM')
        element.click()
        time.sleep(5)
InstaBot('randomusername', 'randompassword')
```

And part the html code (the code concerning said button) is this:

```
 <li class="Ckrof" tabindex="-1" style="transform: translateX(24px);">
 <div class="                    Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95       _4EzTm                                                                                                              " style="width: 125px;">
<div class="_3D7yK" aria-disabled="false" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
<div aria-label="Open Stories" class="aoVrC D1yaK" aria-disabled="true" role="button" tabindex="-1">
<canvas height="109" width="109" style="position: absolute; top: -5px; left: -5px; width: 87px; height: 87px;">
</canvas><div class="tUtVM" style="width: 77px; height: 77px;"><img alt="Harvey ll's profile picture" class="NCYx-" src="https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.12442-15/e35/c0.437.1125.1125a/s150x150/89402896_882451342191220_7293232057833411878_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=104&amp;_nc_ohc=fRWOPUxfMBoAX8E3UGz&amp;_nc_tp=16&amp;oh=b1e61b04306f65b96b55c7fe9992baff&amp;oe=5F63BF3F"></div></div><div class="eXle2">Harvey ll</div></div></div></li>
```

The part that is causing errors is this:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('tUtVM')
element.click()
```

And the error I get is this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".tUtVM"}
```

I've tried using different class names but none of them works!

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - specifically "`DO NOT use images of code`"

Comment: I would suggest using XPath.

Comment: @YunchongJC [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @RandomDavis sorry, im pretty new here, i will check that and change accordingly.

Comment: @Andrej, I tried using xpath but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Where exactly do i add that to? sorry i am still a beginner :)

Comment: Instead of the driver.find_element_by_class_name('tUtVM')use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*div[role='button']/div").

Comment: Also add a webdriver wait to it since you are getting a new page and have no waits between the page loading.

Comment: @arundeepchohan mmm i tried that and got InvalidSelectorException, that its not a valid Xpath expression.

Comment: Any chance that it is an iframe?

Comment: @arundeepchohan no its not in a iframe it seems.

Answer (score 0):

element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@aria-label,"Open Stories")]/following::div')
element.click()

Comment: I tried this but still it cannot locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one element present with the class name `tUtVM`. You can follow below approach to get it resolved.

```
    self.driver.get('{}/{}'.format(self.base_url, 'fatcatharvey'))
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="presentation"]'))
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tUtVM')
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        elementsTemp = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tUtVM')
        elementsTemp.__getitem__(i).click()
        #Compete the task with opened url
        self.driver.back()
```

Comment: Your code may be failing at `element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("cmbtv")`?

Comment: strangely it does work most of the time! But that part has failed for some unknow reason before.